# Android back button issue in Onsen UI with UI-Router

Tags: angular-ui-router, onsen-ui

I tried this example in my Cordova app with onsen-ui and ui-router

```
   UI-Router with Onsen-UI
```

http://codepen.io/argelius/pen/WveKKO

Everything works fine till I click the Android back button from page 2 or page 3, the transition won't work any more.

Is it possible to make the above sample working with Android back button?
Thanks.